# CMake: Error required internal CMake variable not set

Tags: windows, cmake

Windows 10, CMake 3.7.0, CUDA v8.0

CMake immediately fails to find anything.  My CMake file looks as so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
#...
#(other stuff here)
```

As output, I get:

```
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (found version "8.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:1013 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)
```

Why is this happening?  Is there an environment variable I have to set?  I saw in some Ubuntu projects, the variable `CUDA_TOOKIT_ROOT_DIR` had to be set.  However, I set it to what I believe should be the proper location (`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0`) and this didn't seem to do anything.  What do I need to set?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Without a `project()` call, most of the CMake commands do not work. And `find_package()` is one of them.

Usually, only `set()` commands may precede `project()` call, all other commands should follow it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(MyProject) # <-- This defines many internal CMake variables, required for other commands.
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, it happened because I used `add_subdirectory()` for a library containing CUDA code before the `enable_language(CUDA)` in the root `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

My conflict seems to have been a CMakeLists.txt file in a subdirectory with:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES( libfoo 
    PROPERTIES 
       LINKER_LANGUAGE C
)
```

where the top level CMakeLists.txt was defined with

```
PROJECT(foo
   LANGUAGES CXX
)
```

I changed the former from C to CXX, and this silly error message went away.