# include_directories do not include directories

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake

Referring the original project as it is easier to explain.

I'm trying to compile this project:
https://github.com/jbohg/render_kinect

I get the error

```
/home/sarkar/libs/render_kinect/src/kinectSimulator.cpp:57:43: fatal 
error: render_kinect/kinectSimulator.h: No such file or directory
#include <render_kinect/kinectSimulator.h>
                                       ^
```

When clearly `kinectSimulator.h` is present in the include directory. And

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

present in the cmake.

- I changed `#include <render_kinect/kinectSimulator.h>` to `#include "render_kinect/kinectSimulator.h"`.
- Added `include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/renderer_kinect)` to cmake followed by `#include "kinectSimulator.h"` in the source

Nothing seems to work. Looks like `include_directories` function is not affecting at all. Though the paths show up in the

```
get_property(inc_dirs DIRECTORY PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) 
message("inc_dirs = ${inc_dirs}")
```

gives

```
inc_dirs = /home/sarkar/libs/render_kinect/include;other/include/paths
```

Why is this still not working?

**EDIT:**
make verbose do not show -I option.

```
make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/c++  <options>  -o CMakeFiles/RenderKinect.dir/src/kinectSimulator.o -c 
/home/sarkar/libs/render_kinect/src/kinectSimulator.cpp
/home/sarkar/libs/render_kinect/src/kinectSimulator.cpp:57:43: fatal 
error: render_kinect/kinectSimulator.h: No such file or directory
```

Are the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES properties completely being ignored?

Comment: Have you followed the build instruction there https://github.com/jbohg/render_kinect#compilation?

Comment: Of course. There are no specific instructions though.

Comment: Try to add `project()` call before the first `include_directories` call. I heard that without `project` compilation of C++ files is broken sometimes. In any case, using `project()` in any project is a good rule: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017111/cmake-error-required-internal-cmake-variable-not-set/42018800#42018800.

Comment: Hello, I did add project() later, but still it has the same problem. There is no -I in c++ compilation command.