# cmake can't find_package in docker image

Tags: docker, gcc, cmake, openssl

I encountered a problem with cmake in docker, where cmake failed to find OpenSSL package in the system, but I'm sure it's installed. And I see strange errors about required internal CMake variable not set.

[image]

I can compile the same code in normal VM without a problem, but I cannot get it to work in docker.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?
I've uploaded the full code in:
https://gitlab.com/kenjichanhkg/docker_cmake_hello_world.git
Please check out the "cmake_helloworld" branch.

The dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM gcc:latest
COPY . /usr/test/src
WORKDIR /usr/test/src

RUN apt update -y && apt install -y \
    cmake \
    libssl-dev \
    git

RUN ./build.sh

CMD [ "./build/test" ]
```

the cmake file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.13 )

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
project( docker_cmake_hello_world )

add_executable(test main.cpp)

include_directories(  
        ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(
        test
        OpenSSL::SSL
)
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your CMakeLists.txt is wrong. CMake sets up its environment in the `project` command so to use `find_package` properly you need at least move that command after `project`. And the `include_directories` command need to be moved before the `add_executable` command to take effect (maybe you intended to use `target_include_directories`?). As OpenSSL already provides a proper import target OpenSSL::SSL you don't need to add a separate command for the include directories at all.

A proper CMakeLists.txt file for your test program should look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(docker_cmake_hello_world)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
add_executable(test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL)
```

Comment: that's a dummy project, but the real issue is in my existing project, and the cmake files have already been working for years

Comment: As your Github repository does not show a dependency on OpenSSL, I stuck to your CMake file. Nevertheless, you need to move your `find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)`command after the `project` command. See here for a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017111/cmake-error-required-internal-cmake-variable-not-set

Comment: rearrange the project command makes it to work, but this is just a dummy project. In my real project, cmake still cannot locate the OpenSSL cmake module, and I can't reproduce the same problem in the dummy project

Comment: I found where my problem is, it's in my cmake command, I did something like cmake -DOPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib64/libssl.so, which messed things up